# Every Lie group is embedded in a complex Lie group

Tags: differential-geometry, lie-groups, lie-algebras

If $G$ is a real Lie group and $\mathfrak g$ is its Lie algebra. If $\hat{ \mathfrak g}=\mathfrak g+i\mathfrak g$ is the complexifiaction of the Lie algebra and let $\hat G$ be the associated complex Lie group.

Now is $G$ a real Lie subgroup of  $\hat G$? If yes, why this is not a complexification (in general) of $G$? And can we say that every Lie group is embedded as a submanifold in a simply-connected complex Lie group?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, $G$ doesn't have to be a real subgroup of $\hat G$. Let $G$ be the universal covering of $SL(2,\mathbb{R})$. Then $\mathfrak{g}$ is $\mathfrak{sl}(2,\mathbb{R})$ and $\hat{\mathfrak{g}}=\mathfrak{sl}(2,\mathbb{C})$. Therefore, $\hat G$ is $SL(2,\mathbb{C})$. If $G$ was a subgroup of $SL(2,\mathbb{C})$, that would make it a matrix group, but it is well-known that it is not.

Comment: Thank you. But what about my second question. The universal complexification always exists so $\exists \hat G$ complex such that $G$ is embedded in $\hat G$ as a Lie subgroup?

Comment: @Ronald [No](https://www.encyclopediaofmath.org/index.php/Complexification_of_a_Lie_group).